# AngularJS broadcast from $rootScope to modal window scope

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to broadcast from $rootScope to modal window $scope?

My $rootScope is ApplicationController and I'm listening in there to socket.io event. When I handle this event I want to $broadcast to ChatController (modal window) $scope (which might be already opened so resolve won't help me here).

A quick example to demonstrate this issue:

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ApplicationController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <input type="button" value="open modal" ng-click="openModal()">
    <div ng-controller="NotModalController">
      {{fields.field1}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("App", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

  app.controller("ApplicationController", function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.openModal = function() {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'chat.html',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {

        }
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function() {
        console.log('modal closed');
      }, function() {
        console.log('modal dismissed');
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('broadcasting event');
        $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', 'broadcasted value');
      }, 3000);
    };
  });

  app.controller("NotModalController", function($scope) {
    $scope.fields = {
      field1: 'initial'
    };
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {
      $scope.fields.field1 = args;
    });
  });

  app.controller("ModalController", function($scope) {
    $scope.fields = {
      field1: 'initial'
    };
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {
      $scope.fields.field1 = args;
    });
  });

})();
```

modalTemplate.html

```
<div>
  {{fields.field1}}
</div>
```

the plunkr url : http://plnkr.co/edit/9xpwmleZJnAG66cGWcYO

Answer (score 0):

Think you should use $rootScope.$broadcast instead $scope.$broadcast

Comment: Do you inject $rootScope in ApplicationController?

Comment: yes.
I do inject  $rootScope in ApplicationController

Comment: I'm not so familiar with $apply but from my understanding you should use $apply only when taking actions outside of angular scope.
It do work in the plunker but in my application I'm getting an Error: $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress.

Comment: Since you use setTimeout, which will execute a function after a delay you must let Angular know about that, so you wrap its in $apply(). But there may be a problem
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog
To resolve it you may also use $timeout service
http://plnkr.co/edit/6kJrO6ToqisttuiKwbQ3?p=preview
Hope this will help)

Comment: It's works fine with $timeout instead of setTimeOut(), thanks. but my real scenario is socket.io event handler and the setTimeOut purpose was to simulate it.
How can I solve it for a broadcast inside of socket.io event handler?

Comment: Hi! In that case you may continue with setTimeOut() and $apply, but in order to avoid the error you should wrap $scope.$apply in condition: if (!$scope.$$phase) {scope.$apply();}

Comment: Tried that but then again, the modal scope doesn't get updated.